# How do I read this python code? var1 = var2 == var3

Tags: python

I'm struggling to understand what this represents

```
var1 = var2 == var3
```

My guess would be that this is equivalent to:

```
if (var2 == var3):
     var1 = var2
```

Comment: First one will return either `true` or `false` and `var1` will represent this result

Comment: No, it's not equivalent to that at all. It assigns the result of `var2 == var3` to `var1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assignment `var1 = var2 == var3` works more like this:

```
if var2 == var3:
    var1 = True
else:
    var1 = False
```

If you evaluate the expression `var2 == var3` on the REPL you will get `True` or `False` depending on they comparing equal or not. In Python you can assign any expression to a variable so the resulting value would be assigned to var1 in your example.

In Python `a == b` is an expression but the assignment `a = b` is a statement. In many languages both are expressions - for example in Javascript you are allowed to do (although not very good style):

```
a == (b = c)
```

In Python it is not allowed (SyntaxError):

```
a == (b = c)
```

The controverse [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) introduces the new assignment operator `:=` that is an expression.

Answer (score 2):

Equality operator `==` has precedence over `=` assignment. So this equates to:

```
var1 = (var2 == var3)  # Boolean
```

The `==` operator itself will return either `True` or `False`; it is this value that is assigned.

Answer (score 2):

```
var1 = var2 == var3
```

Means:

1. create a variable called `var1`
2. Assign it to the True False Boolean which is `var2` equals to `var3` (using the `==` operator)

Here's an example:

```
>>> var2=1
>>> var3=1
>>> var2==var3
True
>>> var1 = var2==var3
>>> var1
True
>>>
```

Comment: Ah, beat me to it :)

Comment: @ViaTech That happens to me a lot too, 

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is incorrect. The code you posted would be this:

```
var2 = 1
var3 = 1

var1 = var2 == var3

#var1 is true because var2 and var3 are equal
```